# Tablesorter's filter_selectSource removes options not available for current page with server-side pagination and select options preparation

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, tablesorter

I'm preparing arrays with options for Tablesorter's [filter_selectSource](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) in Python/Django. Because initially, it worked very strange for me when I switched to server-side filtering. The dropdown options did show up only when I've type one symbol in one of the 'search' filters and then every time it showed select options available one step before. 
And then I've decided to try and make most of the  work on server-side

players.views

```
def skaters_averages_json(request, page, sort_col, filt_col, rookie_filt):

    start = utils.PAGE_SIZE_2*(page - 1)
    end = start + utils.PAGE_SIZE_2
    skaters = Skater.objects.select_related('team')

    filtering = utils.filter_columns(filt_col)
    if filtering:
        skaters = utils.apply_filters(skaters, filtering)

    if utils.rookie_filter(rookie_filt):
        skaters = skaters.filter(rookie=True)

    sorting = utils.sorting_columns(sort_col)
    one_page_slice = utils.sort_table(sorting, skaters)[start:end]

    skaters_json = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', one_page_slice,
                                                    use_natural_foreign_keys=True))
    domain = request.get_host()
    total_rows = skaters.count()
    data = utils.process_json(domain, skaters_json, total_rows, page)

    data['filter_select'] = {
        **utils.filter_select_opts(skaters, 3, 'position_abbr'),
        **utils.filter_select_opts(skaters, 4, 'team__abbr'),
        **utils.filter_select_opts(skaters, 5, 'nation_abbr'),
    }

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

players.utils

```
def filter_select_opts(skaters_query, col_number, field_name):
    uniques = list(skaters_query.values_list(field_name, flat=True).distinct())
    return {col_number: sorted(uniques, key=lambda x: (x is None, x))}
```

So my JSONResponse looks like this.

Page 1

```
{
  "total": 41,
  "rows": [
    [row 1],
    ...
    [row 25]
  ],

  "filter_select": {
    "3": [
      "C",
      "D",
      "LW",
      "RW"
    ],
    "4": [
      "ANA",
      "BOS",
      "BUF",
      "CAR",
      "CBJ",
      "CGY",
      "CHI",
      "COL",
      "DAL",
      "EDM",
      "FLA",
      "MIN",
      "MTL",
      "NJD",
      "NSH",
      "NYI",
      "PHI",
      "PIT",
      "SJS",
      "TOR",
      "VAN",
      "VGK",
      "WPG"
    ],
    "5": [
      "FIN"
    ]
  }
}
```

Page 2

```
{
  "total": 41,
  "rows": [
    [row 26],
    ...
    [row 41]
  ],

  "filter_select": {
  "3": [
    "C",
    "D",
    "LW",
    "RW"
  ],
  "4": [
    "ANA",
    "BOS",
    "BUF",
    "CAR",
    "CBJ",
    "CGY",
    "CHI",
    "COL",
    "DAL",
    "EDM",
    "FLA",
    "MIN",
    "MTL",
    "NJD",
    "NSH",
    "NYI",
    "PHI",
    "PIT",
    "SJS",
    "TOR",
    "VAN",
    "VGK",
    "WPG"
  ],
  "5": [
    "FIN"
  ]
}
}
```

The second page of the applied filter's response shows the same values for `filter_select` But when I look at the same pages after it is processed by `filter_selectSource` it shows only options available on the currently visible page. 
Is there a way to override this behavior?

Read the docs for [filter_selectSource](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) and [getOptions](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#function-getoptions). Couldn't find what I want.

external.js

```
let selectOptions;

$("#tab1")
  .tablesorter({
      headers: {
          0: {sorter: false, filter: false},
          1: {filter: false},
          2: {filter: false},
      },

      widgets: ['filter'],
      widgetOptions : {
      filter_selectSource: selectOptions,
      filter_reset: '.reset',
      filter_external : '.select',
  }
})

.tablesorterPager({
    container: $(".pager-s"),
    size: 25,
    output: '{page} / {totalPages}',
    savePages: false,
    fixedHeight: false,
    ajaxUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/skaters_averages_json/{page+1}/{sort:col}/{filter:fcol}',
    customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
    if ($("#tab1").data('filter_value')) {
          return url += '/rookie_filter=' + $("#tab1").data('filter_value');
    };
        return url += '/rookie_filter=';
    },

    ajaxObject: {
        success: function(data) {
          selectOptions = data['filter_select'];
          $("#tab1").trigger("updateAll");
          console.log(selectOptions);
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
      },
    });

$('.rookie-filter').on('change', function(){
    let checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    $("#tab1").data('filter_value', checked).trigger('pagerUpdate', 1);
    if (checked) {
      $(this).attr('title', 'Show all players')
    } else {
      $(this).attr('title', 'Show rookies only')
    };
});

$('.reset').on('click', function(){
  $('.rookie-filter').prop('checked', false);
  $("#tab1").data('filter_value', $(this).is(":checked")).trigger('pagerUpdate');
});

$('table').bind("sortEnd", function(){
    $(this).trigger('pageSet', 1);
  });
```

I'm also logging `selectOptions` in my external .js file to make sure I'm getting what's expected.

UPDATE.
Have been trying to make it work with `buildSelect`, as @Mottie suggested in the comment.
As it turned out, `filter_selectSource` actuall`didn't accept my variable in`filter_selectSource: selectOptions`, the only line that makes a difference is`$("#tab1").trigger("updateAll")`in`ajaxObject`. Tablesorter then automatically shows the options available on the current page.

So, now I'm struggling with triggering updates for a filter row.
I'm able to load expected options for one column at a time, but the table doesn't work because of the `too much recursion` error.
`$('body').trigger(filter_event)` in every `filter_selectSource` causing enormous amount of updating a table. But without it options for dropdown menus are empty. I've tried to bind this update for different [events](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#events). Like `filterInit`. Didn't work for me.
Take a look at my updated script below. Any suggestions of how to make it update a filter row without repeating it multiple times?

```
$("#tab1").data('statType', 'tot');
let pos = [];
let team = [];
let nation = [];
let filter_event = jQuery.Event("load_filter_select");

$("#tab1")
  .tablesorter({
      headers: {
          0: {sorter: false, filter: false},
          1: {filter: false},
          2: {filter: false},
      },

      widgets: ['filter'],
      widgetOptions : {

        filter_selectSource: {
          3 : function(table, column, onlyAvail) {
            result = pos;
            $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect(table, column, result, true);
            $('body').trigger(event);
          },

          4 : function(table, column) {
            result = team;
            $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect(table, column, result, true);
            $('body').trigger(filter_event);
          },

          5 : function(table, column) {
            result = nation;
            $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect(table, column, result, true);
            $('body').trigger(filter_event);
          },
        },

      filter_reset: '.reset',
      filter_external : '.select',
  }
})

.tablesorterPager({
    container: $(".pager-s"),
    size: 25,
    output: '{page} / {totalPages}',
    savePages: false,
    fixedHeight: false,
    ajaxUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/skaters_averages_json?/{page+1}/{sort:col}/{filter:fcol}',
    customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
      urlParts = url.split('?');
      url = urlParts[0] + `/${$("#tab1").data('statType')}` + urlParts[1];

      if ($("#tab1").data('filter_value')) {
            return url += '/rookie_filter=' + $("#tab1").data('filter_value');
      };
          return url += '/rookie_filter=';
    },

    ajaxObject: {
        success: function(data) {
          pos = data['filter_select'][3];
          team = data['filter_select'][4];
          nation = data['filter_select'][5];

          $('body').trigger(filter_event);

        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
      },
    });

$('body').on('load_filter_select', function(){
    $("#tab1").trigger('update');
});
```

Comment: Maybe try the [example from the docs](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) that uses `buildSelect`?

Comment: @Mottie, I've updated my answer, please take a look, if you have time.

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't need to trigger an update after calling `buildSelect`. And actually, I think, you could call the `buildSelect` function from within the ajax callback instead of adding it all into the `filter_selectSource` option. Also, I don't recommend triggering an `updateAll` unless the table header content changes. Would it be possible for you to set up a demo? Then it would be easier for me to help you.

Comment: @Mottie, wow, it works like charm! With just a couple of lines in the ajax callback - `table = $("#tab1");`  `options = data['filter_select'];`  `for (let column = 3; column <= 5; column++) { $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect(table, column, options[column], true);  };`

Comment: @Mottie, would like to add this as an answer? Or I should do it myself?

Comment: @Mottie, regarding `updateAll`. For some reason, it didn't work with `update` in that case. I couldn't really figure out why. I could try and set up a demo, you could look at it if it's no bother for you.

Comment: You can add it as an answer, and I'll upvote you! And sure, I don't mind checking out a demo. Do you still need to trigger an update?

Comment: @Mottie, ok, no, I don't need to trigger an update now. I just had no idea why `updateAll` instead of `update` worked at some point. It was just random guess, no logic behind it. And I don't like things like that :). Not sure it would be a good time investment now, trying to investigate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the great help of [Mottie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145346/mottie) I've been able to solve the problem.

I shouldn't have to actually trigger any updates. Just load the options from AJAX callback using `buildSelect` function.
So, the full script that makes select filters work properly looks like this:

```
$("#tab1").data('statType', 'tot');

$("#tab1")
  .tablesorter({
      widgets: ['filter'],
      widgetOptions: {
          filter_selectSource : {
             ".filter-select" : function() { return null; }
          },

      }
})

.tablesorterPager({
    container: $(".pager-s"),
    size: 25,
    output: '{page} / {totalPages}',
    savePages: false,
    fixedHeight: false,
    ajaxUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax_players?/{page+1}/{sort:col}/{filter:fcol}',
    customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
      urlParts = url.split('?');
      url = urlParts[0] + `/${$("#tab1").data('statType')}` + urlParts[1];

      if ($("#tab1").data('filter_value')) {
            return url += '/rookie_filter=' + $("#tab1").data('filter_value');
      };
          return url += '/rookie_filter=';
    },

    ajaxObject: {
        success: function(data) {
          table = $("#tab1");
          options = data['filter_select'];

          for (let column = 3; column <= 5; column++) {
              $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect(table, column, options[column], true);
          };
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
      },
    });
```

UPDATE. I've actually just figured out why this solution was not working as expected in some cases. I forgot to add `filter_selectSource : { ".filter-select" : function() { return null; } },` to the `widget-options`. Without the function returning null `filter_selectSource` was trying to override the options made by `buildSelect`. I've edited the code.